# PSQLException: The column name clazz_ was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch a `PlaceEntity`. I've previously stored a bunch of `GooglePlaceEntity` objects where

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
)
public class PlaceEntity extends AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "google_place")
public class GooglePlaceEntity extends PlaceEntity {
    // Additional fields ..
}
```

---

However, neither do I want to send information stored in `google_place` nor do I want to load it unnecessarily. For this reason I am only fetching

```java
public interface PlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "" +
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM place " +
            "WHERE earth_distance( " +
            "   ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), " +
            "   ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude) " + 
            ") < :radius",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<PlaceEntity> findNearby(@Param("latitude") Float latitude,
                                 @Param("longitude") Float longitude,
                                 @Param("radius") Integer radius);

}
```

and what I get is this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name clazz_ was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2588) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getInt(PgResultSet.java:2481) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ...
```

I am able to run this statement in pure PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM place WHERE 
earth_distance( 
  ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), 
  ll_to_earth(17.2592522, 25.0632745)
) < 1500;
```

but not using the `JpaRepository`.

And by the way, fetching a `GooglePlaceEntity` is working however:

```java
@Query(value = "" +
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM place JOIN google_place ON google_place.id = place.id " +
        "WHERE earth_distance( " +
        "   ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), " +
        "   ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude) " + 
        ") < :radius",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<GooglePlaceEntity> findNearby(@Param("latitude") Float latitude,
                                   @Param("longitude") Float longitude,
                                   @Param("radius") Integer radius);
```

Comment: deleted answer, found a pretty identical one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140992/jpa-native-query-for-entity-with-inheritance

Comment: @Zeromus I would love to hear the technical story behind this. I debugged the code and it seems that it branches when it detects that a class has been derived and then it tries to build such a joined query which it, at least as I see it, shouldn't do. However, writing native queries is not the reason why I am using Hibernate. At this point I converted the *is-a* to a *has-a* relation.

Answer (score 11):

In case of `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`, when you retrieve data without `nativeQuery=True` in *JPA repository*, **Hibernate** will execute SQL like the following:

```
SELECT
table0_.id as id1_1_,
table0_.column2 as column2_2_1_,
... (main_table cols)
table0_1_.column1 as column1_1_0_,
... (table1 to N-1 cols)
table0_N_.column1 as column1_1_9_,
... (tableN-th cols)
CASE WHEN table0_1_.id is not null then 1
    ... (table1 to N-1 cols)
    WHEN table0_N_.id is not null then N
    WHEN table0_.id is not null then 0
    END as clazz_
FROM table table0_
left outer join table1 table0_1_ on table0_.id=table0_1_.id
... (other tables join)
left outer join table2 table0_N_ on table0_.id=table0_N_.id
```

From the above SQL you can see **clazz** specification. If you want to map **ResultSet** to your super instance (PlaceEntity), you should specify **clazz_** column in **SELECT** by yourself.

In your case it will be:

```
@Query(value = "" +
            "SELECT *, 0 AS clazz_ " +
            "FROM place " +
            "WHERE earth_distance( " +
            "   ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), " +
            "   ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude) " + 
            ") < :radius",
            nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: @AradGonen I think it's because of `InheritanceType.JOINED`. When you are mapping your result set to class , it will ask for some sort of **discriminator column**, which is not provided in `nativeQuery=true`. But I also don't know why it works for derived class and does not work for super class.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this, works with MySQL as well

Comment: Also works for `@Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the name of the class instead of the table name on the query. Change **place** to **PlaceEntity**.

```
@Query(value = "" +
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM place JOIN google_place ON google_place.id = place.id " +
    "WHERE earth_distance( " +
    "   ll_to_earth(place.latitude, place.longitude), " +
    "   ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude) " + 
    ") < :radius",
    nativeQuery = true)
List<GooglePlaceEntity> findNearby(@Param("latitude") Float latitude,
                               @Param("longitude") Float longitude,
                               @Param("radius") Integer radius);
```